# What mean packaging:bundle mean inside the POM?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-bundle-plugin

When I download the protobuf-javalite-3.17.3 pom: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.17.3/protobuf-javalite-3.17.3.pom I can see inside

```
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
```

What packaging : bundle mean exactly? on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.17.3/ I can see that their is a `protobuf-javalite-3.17.3.jar` but no `protobuf-javalite-3.17.3.bundle`, so do I need to download instead the `protobuf-javalite-3.17.3.jar` ?

Comment: Packging bundle means it will create an OSGi bundle. A bundle is simply a jar file with special information in the `MANIFEST.MF` file...

Comment: @khmarbaise so you mean that in my project I can simply include the equivalent jar file when I encounter a packaging: bundle ? here i just need to include in my project protobuf-javalite-3.17.3.jar right ?

Comment: Yes you can use the usual dependency which means a jar file ... that should work.. Apart from using an old version which 3.17.X is use a more recent versions ....

Comment: I allowed myself to formulate an extended version of @khmarbaise 's comments as an answer post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the question has basically been answered in the comments by @khmarbaise, some references and elaboration might be useful.

According to the chapter in Maven's POM Reference on [Packaging](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#packaging), the `<packaging>` tag in a `.pom` file defines, how a project file has to be packaged. Thereby:

> The current core packaging values are: [`pom`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#4-pom), [`jar`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#1-jar), [`maven-plugin`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#5-maven-plugin), [`ejb`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#6-ejb), [`war`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#2-war), [`ear`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#3-ear), [`rar`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#7-rar).

The default is `jar`. [Other packaging types](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#other-packaging-types) can be provided through plugins.

Now, `<packaging>bundle</packaging>` refers to an [OSGi bundle](https://www.baeldung.com/osgi#osgi-basics).

> Technically, a [OSGi] bundle is just a `jar` file with a `MANIFEST.MF` file containing some OSGi-specific headers.

For an overview you might be interested in an [Introduction to OSGi](https://www.baeldung.com/osgi).

So, yes. You will want to download the `protobuf-javalite-3.17.3.jar`. When unzipping it and taking a look into the `MANIFEST.MF` file you will discover the OSGi-related entry

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
```